# How to convert s57 to shape via ogr2ogr?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, s-57

Trying conver s57 files to shape. First added enviroment variable:

```
OGR_S57_OPTIONS
with value
RETURN_PRIMITIVES=ON,RETURN_LINKAGES=ON,LNAM_REFS=ON
```

Then run:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite  -skipfailures "US1GC09M_1.shp" -nlt point "US1GC09M.000"  wrecks
```

But have got multiple errors:

```
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field LNAM_REFS. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field FFPT_RIND. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field NAME_RCNM. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field NAME_RCID. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field ORNT. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field USAG. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field MASK. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field QUASOU. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field STATUS. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field TECSOU. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
```

Gdal version:

```
GDAL 3.3.1, released 2021/06/28
```

ANy advice? I forgot to do something?

Comment: You cannot save attributes that contain a list of values into shapefile format. You can have a try with ogr2ogr option `-splitlistfields` and split such attributes into many regular string fields.

Comment: The s57 driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/s57.html has also an option LIST_AS_STRING=ON.

Comment: @user30184 `-splitlistfields` option quiet helps. I mean errors gone, but ofc the option creates more fields in output file than in input file.

Comment: @user30184 I tryed `LIST_AS_STRING=ON` but a still got same errors when i ran `ogr2ogr` without `-splitlistfields`. So i even don't understand that `OGR_S57_OPTIONS` variable works or not. Is there any way to check it?

Comment: It is natural that splitfields adds fields. That is the intention of the option. S57 supports list attributes, for example `COLOR=1 COLOR=4`. With shapefile there are two options: add both values into one `COLOR=1,4` or split the attribute `COLOR_1=1 COLOR_2=4`. Convert data into for example GML if you want to preserve list attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded some test data from https://ienccloud.us/ienc/products/files/u37/ienc_s57/U37UM723.ZIP

Test 1 with OGR_S57_options

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" wrecks01.shp U37UM723.000 wrecks --config OGR_S57_OPTIONS "LIST_AS_STRING=ON"
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field LNAM_REFS. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field FFPT_RIND. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
```

Test 2 without OGR_S57_options

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" wrecks02.shp U37UM723.000 wrecks
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field LNAM_REFS. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support IntegerList type for field FFPT_RIND. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field QUASOU. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field STATUS. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for field TECSOU. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type StringList on shapefile layers.
```

With LIST_AS_STRING=ON option ogr2ogr prints less warnings so obviously the variable works. I do not know why all the warnings are not removed but my test data was not best possible because it does not contain any data for the stringList/integerList attributes.

Comment: `-splitlistfields` is the best solution for me. But unfortinatly i use ogr2ogr.py (https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py) that doesn't support this option. So i just create empty shp and populate data from s57, converting `StringList` and `IntList` fields into string. Code could be found here http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#filter-and-select-input-shapefile-to-new-output-shapefile-like-ogr2ogr-cli

Comment: Don't use ogr2ogr.py. There is a Python equivalent of ogr2ogr "gdal.VectorTranslate" https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslate.